# How can I sync a google doc from my G-drive with my kindle account?

Tags: kindle, kindle-paperwhite, amazon

I know that Kindle fire allowed for document syncing with the Amazon Cloud Drive, but I was wondering if the same can be done with my Kindle Paperwhite.

Answer (score 0):

No the only ways to get data onto a Kindle ebook reader is

1. Link to a PC/Mac via USB and the PC sees the Kindle as an external disk you can copy to (or use Calibre for more control)
2. Email the document to the kindle email address for your Kindle.
3. Not for your docs but you can download your Amazon purchased ebooks.